# Can there be two separate key pairs for different users in AWS EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key-pair

I am trying to access an EC2 instance from a colleague's AWS account and I am wondering if I can have a key pair that works as that on his machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keypairs are a standard means of logging into a Linux computer. They are not specific to Amazon EC2 instances.

The way it works is that you initiate an ssh session by providing:

- A private key
- A username
- The DNS Name or IP address of the destination computer

The destination computer receives the request, then looks in the designated user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. So, if the username is `ec2-user`, it looks in:

```
/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If there is a public key in that file that matches the private key that was provided, then the ssh connection is established.

So, if you wish to access another person's computer, you should give them your public key (that is, the public half of your private keypair). They should add that key to the desired user directory as shown above. You will then be able to login to that computer via ssh.

They could also, if desired, create a different user on that computer for you to use. They just need to add the public key in the correct directory.